# Create meaningful etckeeper commit messages

Tags: debian, logs, git, gentoo, etckeeper

I want to keep track of the `/etc` changes with [etckeeper](http://etckeeper.branchable.com/)

Unfortunately, the commit messages are the same for all commits

```
saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to emerge run
```

I wish there would be something more descriptive like

```
apt-get install foo
```

on debian based systems or

```
emerge foo
```

on gentoo based systems when reading the logs with `git log`. 
Is there a hook script, I can use for this?

Comment: Notice that with things stored in a git repository, there is nothing that is stopping you from changing the commit message to whatever you want with an interactive rebase (or possibly automate with filter-branch).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The changelog message comes from one of the hook scripts of etckeeper. For example the “saving uncommitted changes” message is from `/etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/50uncommitted-changes`.

But if you want truly meaningful messages for changes that you made, a computer cannot generate them for you. (Changes resulting from apt-get or emerge operation do get a meaningful messages listing the packages that got installed, upgraded or removed.) You need to run `etckeeper commit` or `$vcs commit` and enter a meaningful message. To prevent apt-get or emerge from running if there are uncommitted changes, edit `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` and uncomment the line `AVOID_COMMIT_BEFORE_INSTALL=1` (and `AVOID_DAILY_AUTOCOMMITS=1` if it's commented out).